# Which DynamoDB call to use to get 15 items from dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to get 15 items out of a DynamoDB (same table/region). What should I use?
loop 15 times through get-item, transact-get-items or batch-get-item?

Answer (score 0):

`batch-get-item` is going to be the most performant. That's the whole reason it exists in addition to `get-item`. You would only use `transact-get-items` if you want to retrieve the items in an atomic, "transactional", way.